# How to convert subprocess.communicate() to utf-8 String?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, subprocess

I made a subprocess, but the output is weird:

```
(b'Ping: 3.425 ms\r\nDownload: 1167.08 Mbit/s\r\nUpload: 314.93 Mbit/s\r\n', None)
```

Whereas I was expecting:

```
Ping: 3.425 ms
Download: 1167.08 Mbit/s
Upload: 314.93 Mbit/s
```

And here is my Code:

```
process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("speedtest-cli", "--simple", stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
output = await process.communicate()
print(output)
```

The function must also be asynchronous.

Comment: I hope that your real use case is different, because here, `asyncio` is useless. `speedtest-cli` runs in a different process, so `subprocess.Popen` is enough to have both processes to run in parallel.

Comment: Oh yeah. I use this for a Discord Bot. When i type the command for a Speedtest with no asyncio, the bot dont responds to other commands. thats the reason it needs to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output you're getting is in a tuple, you're able to extract an element with a given index:

```py
>>> data = output[0]
b'Ping: 3.425 ms\r\nDownload: 1167.08 Mbit/s\r\nUpload: 314.93 Mbit/s\r\n'
```

And you're able to decode it with the built-in `.decode()` method:

```py
>>> data = output[0].decode("utf-8")
Ping: 3.425 ms
Download: 1167.08 Mbit/s
Upload: 314.93 Mbit/s
```

---

**Reference:**

- [`Process.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process.communicate) - "Return a tuple `(stdout_data, stderr_data)`".
  You expected an output, hence the first element, and you didn't get an error, hence the second element.

Comment: I had a quick look to see if this library had an `encoding="utf-8"` kwarg like the normal `subprocess.run()` does, which would auto-decode all output. The answer is: No. So manual decoding is the only way. The manual explicitly says that this API doesn't work like the other Python process APIs: *"All other keyword arguments are passed to subprocess.Popen without interpretation, except for bufsize, universal_newlines, shell, text, encoding and errors, which should not be specified at all."*